# Ubuntu on an old ia64 HP server

Tags: system-installation

I want to install 14.04 (Trusty) 64bit, on and old ia64 HP BL860c server.

Does someone know if this is supported by Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

10.04 (Lucid) was the last Ubuntu release that supported ia64: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2010-August/000441.html